# Google Cloud Send Email Upon File Upload

Tags: google-app-engine, email, embedded-linux, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to Google Cloud, I'm trying to find out is there a way where everytime I upload a file to the Cloud Storage I can have an instance send an email to the user? I already have my device uploading files to Cloud Storage without any issues, however the device is also sending the emails to - and since it's an embedded application I'd prefer to off load that task.

Comment: How do you upload files on Cloud Storage? Are you using App Engine to handle that or doing that directly via GCS?

Comment: Directly via GCS I have a Python script set up to do the uploading

Comment: koi.. otherwise you could use the https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/ after a successful upload.. but now you can still use it in combination with notifications that were mentioned in the answers..

Comment: Alright great I'll look into using that then thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [GCS Object change notifications](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification).  Its the more generic answer for "how do I take action when a file changes in GCS", but you could certainly implement a notification handler in appengine to handle your email notifications.